# Firebase retrieve data when certain child value within child changes

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have a firebase realtime database which keeps users messages. At the moment I have it so when a users 'inbox' child is updated it retrieves the latest data for that child, for example:

```
firebase.database().ref('users/'+firebase.auth().currentUser.uid+'/inbox/').on('child_changed', function(snapshot) {
// get the latest data
});
```

But when using this method, if a message is deleted by the user, it will retrieve the child data again. Is there anyway to only retrieve the latest data only if a child inside of that child is updated?

So in my database I have it set out like this:

```
{
  "users" : {
   "IPenCEXKICROYWzYtyzybzhem9R2" : {

      "inbox" : {
        "32tcqIRaG2RAgb9dTwmcgKoVPhd2IPenCEXKICROYWzYtyzybzhem9R2" : {
          "lastmessagetimestamp" : 1564139876817,

        "conversationmessages" : {

          "-LhKZ-MUVxbyRcqp-Q_c" : {
            "from" : "32tcqIRaG2RAgb9dTwmcgKoVPhd2",
            "messagetext" : "this is a test message",
            }
          },
        },
      },
    },
  }
}
```

I am saving that timestamp of the last message a user receives. So I would like it to only retrieve data if the 'lastmessagetimestamp' child value is changed.

The simplest way I could think of doing this would be:

```
firebase.database().ref('users/'+firebase.auth().currentUser.uid+'/inbox/**conversationid**/lastmessagetimestamp/').on('child_changed', function(snapshot) {
// get the latest data
});
```

But because my 'conversationid' is randomly generated and is not unique, it cannot be done. Is there a way to possibly skip the 'conversationid' and go directly to the 'lastmessagetimestamp'?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a snippet of the actual JSON, instead of the database diagram (as text, no screenshot please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen just added it

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish, so hope that somebody else understands it better.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Basically im just trying to retrieve the data in the 'inbox' child but only if 'lastmessagetimestamp' is changed in any of the childs. But because the 'conversationid' is always different I cant directly query it.

Comment: That is correct: you can't listen for changes in specific properties. If you need that, create a separate list that only contains the properties whose changes you want to listen to.